# How can I tell my Helm Chart to ignore the default ingress-nginx and create a new one?

Tags: kubernetes, helm, ingress, ingress-nginx

Whenever I run `helm install` on the chart I'm making I see this,

> Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: rendered manifests contain a resource that already exists. Unable to continue with install: IngressClass "nginx" in namespace "" exists and cannot be imported into the current release: invalid ownership metadata; annotation validation error: key "meta.helm.sh/release-name" must equal "acme-1681486075": current value is "acmecorp-nginx"; annotation validation error: key "meta.helm.sh/release-namespace" must equal "acme": current value is "default"

What concerns me here is this part

> Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: rendered manifests contain a resource that already exists. Unable to continue with install: IngressClass "nginx" in namespace "" exists and **cannot be imported into the current release**

I don't want to import the cluster default. I want to create and bring my own ingress controller with my helm chart. Why is it still thinking this is a default to be imported?

```
dependencies:
  ...
  - name: "ingress-nginx"
    repository: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx
    version: 4.x.x
controller:
  electionID: ingress-controller-leader
  ingressClassResource:
    name: internal-nginx  # default: nginx
    enabled: true
    default: false
    controllerValue: "k8s.io/internal-ingress-nginx"  # default: k8s.io/ingress-nginx
```

What is the syntax in a Chart.yaml to list ingress-nginx as a dependency for a multiple ingress install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me the problem here was spelling, believe it or not. I just had to lowercase the `release` name in the chart. I figured this out, by dumping my helm to a yaml using `helm template` and then applying that. When I did this is what I got

> Error from server (Invalid): error when creating "nginx-ingress-install.yaml": ServiceAccount "release-name-FooBar" is invalid: metadata.name: Invalid value: "release-name-FooBar": a lowercase RFC 1123 subdomain must consist of lower case alphanumeric characters, '-' or '.', and must start and end with an alphanumeric character (e.g. 'example.com', regex used for validation is 'a-z0-9?(.a-z0-9?)*')

I just had to change my release from `FooBar` to `foobar`